# Querying documents into one specific property in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I wanted to query all "doc" properties inside the "doc", like a nested. I guess you can understand further what I want to explain from the code below:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/stationDB");

const docSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  naturka: String,
  address: String,
  coefficient: String,
  wheel: String,
  weight: Number
})

const stockSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  rollingStockNumber: String,
  docs: [docSchema]
});


const Doc = mongoose.model('Doc', docSchema);
const Stock = mongoose.model('Stock', stockSchema);

let doc;
  for(i=0; i<naturkaMinifiedArrayReady.length; i++){
    const doc = new Doc({
      naturka: naturkaMinifiedArrayReady[i],
      address: arrayOfWayPlanForm[i],
      coefficient: valueOfCarLength[i],
      wheel: numberOfWheels[i],
      weight: valueOfCarWeight[i]
    });
    docs = doc
  };

  const stock = new Stock({
    rollingStockNumber: rollingStock,
    docs: docs
  });
  stock.save((err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.redirect('/')
    }
  });
```

I have inserted 8 documents, but returning only the last document as you see:

```
{ _id: new ObjectId("62a1ac800d9d39966878ebb8"), rollingStockNumber: '922698012567076507200129101700057022060000000', docs: [ { naturka: '08 94331444 0271 030 72240 00300 0012 0 0 0 0 01/00 96 04 105 0200 OXP', address: 'Toshkent', coefficient: '1.05', wheel: '4', weight: 50, _id: new ObjectId("62a1ac800d9d39966878ebb7") } ], __v: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doc defined with let is an array, but you do =. If you add the data to the array with push, your problem will be solved.

```
let docs = [];
  for(i=0; i<naturkaMinifiedArrayReady.length; i++){
    const doc = new Doc({
      naturka: naturkaMinifiedArrayReady[i],
      address: arrayOfWayPlanForm[i],
      coefficient: valueOfCarLength[i],
      wheel: numberOfWheels[i],
      weight: valueOfCarWeight[i]
    });
    docs.push(doc)
  };
```

Comment: Thanks, one more question bro. How can I access to only "address" property?  "const addresses = foundStocks.map((stock) => stock.docs.address);" doesn't work (

Comment: The doc in stock is also an array, so you need to for in it as well. But you don't need to do it one by one with map. You can look at the query array 'in' operator property from the Mongoose documentation.